# Facebook SDK 3.0 freezes on session state OPENING in Android

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication

I am using the Facebook SDK 3.0.2 to share a simple URL on facebook through my application.
I am not using Fragments but using ActivityGroup in a tabhost. I want to share from an Activity within the Activity group. Below is the code I am using to initiate a session:

```
Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
        {
            // callback when session changes state
            public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
            {

                if (session.isOpened())
                {
                    publishFeedDialog(name, caption, description, link, urlPicture, listenerShareFacebook);
                } else {
                    AlAinZooUtils.LOG("----- Session not opened in Manager ------ "+state);
                    if(exception != null) {
                        AlAinZooUtils.LOG("----- exception in opening the session ------ "+exception.getMessage());
                        listenerShareFacebook.onShareFacebookFailure(exception.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that the session never returns OPENED. It always shows OPENING and freezes. There is no exception thrown as well. I have no clue what the issue could be.

I have also overridden the onActivityResult method in the activity and the Parent Activity but it does not get called either. Please guide me to get it working.

Answer (score 4):

Dont forget to add onActivityResult method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: I have added that in both parent and the activity but it does not get triggered.